# Measurable functions of sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let f and g be $\epsilon$-measurable functions on E. Show that the following sets
are in $\epsilon$:

1) ${f >g}$

2) ${f <g}$

3) ${f\ne g}$

4) ${f =g}$

5) ${f ≥g}$

6)${f ≤g}$.

I know {f > g} is the set of all x for which f(x) > r and g(x) < r for some rational number r. I'm just having trouble putting that knowledge in to action. I'm an Economics major, but trying to self study some probability to try my hand at Actuarial Science. Just browsing around and found this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remember that "all/every" <=> intersection $\cap$ and "there exists/for some" <=> union $\cup$.
Also, "or" <=> union and "and" <=> intersection. 
Now how do you write the set of $x$ such that $\exists r$, $f(x)>r>g(x)$ ?

Comment: "I know {f > g} is the set of all x for which f(x) > r and g(x) < r for some rational number r" Right, and what can you say about the sets {f > r} and {g > r}?

Comment: @did f(x) > r > g(x)? I feel as though i'm making this harder than i need to but for some reason I'm not following. Or do you mean that the set {f > r} > {g > r}?

Comment: You simply did not address the question in my comment. Again: what do we know about {f > r}?